# remap keyboard in Linux like macos (left alt + l = @)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a german macintosh keyboard layout on my macbook pro late 2013 which now runs ubuntu. I want to type "@" just like the way it is done in macos: pressing left alt and l. In the default setting this can only be done via right alt and l.

Swapping is not an option, because i type {} with the left alt+8,9

kinto.sh is also not an option because of that. using kinto.sh makes alt+l an @ but {} can then be typed by using left alt only.

Can you please give a hint how to type @ with left alt + l on a german macintosh keyboard with macintosh keyboardlayout?

i tried kinto.sh but it does not behave like I expect

Comment: This is not a programming question, it probably belongs on https://askubuntu.com